PostgreSQL: How to pass multiple parameters from command line?
I am following the other topic, but unfortunately i couldn't comment on that as i don't meet requirement to comment (less reputation). If someone can help me,  i really appreciate it.
topic is here
text
Let's say i have 2 variables here
psql ...... -v v1=50 -v v2=100

I know that using only 1 variable will work fine
SELECT format($$
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _number1 numeric := %L;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%%', _number1;
END
$do$;
$$, :'v1',:'v2')\gexec

But how to deal with many variables ? I tried to run it like this but not sure if it is correct or not.
SELECT format($$
DO
$do$
DECLARE
   _number1 numeric := %L;
   _number2 numeric := %L;
BEGIN
  RAISE NOTICE '%%', _number1;
  RAISE NOTICE '%%', _number2;
END
$do$;
$$, :'v1',:'v2')\gexec


unfortunately, there is not nice solution for working with high number parameters with using "some" arrays. Maybe you can use parameters in format JSON_ARRAY, and then pass just only one parameter, and next convert it to plpgsql array inside procedure.

Your code is correct, and that will work with many variables.
The %L format specifiers will be substituted left to right: the second argument to format() will replace the first %L, the third argument the second %L and so on. If you want to change the order, you can use the more explicit %3$L, which will be replaced by the fourth argument of format(), no matter where in the format string it occurs.
